# Remove input text when click button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to remove input's val when clicking a button that appear when focusing on input.

This is my html:

```
<div class="search-area">
                <form action="#" id="ingredientSearchForm">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Arama" id="ingredientsSearch"/>
                    <span class="clearable"></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <input id="ingredientSearchSubmit" type="submit" class="hidden" placeholder="Arama"/>

                </form>
            </div>
```

And this is javascript function:

```
var searchinput = $(".search-area").find("input");


        searchinput.focus(function(){
            $(this).data('placeholder',$(this).attr('placeholder'));
            $(this).attr('placeholder','');
            $(this).siblings(".clearable").show();



        });

        $(".search-area").find(".clearable").on("click", function() {
            $(this).val('');
        });
        searchinput.blur(function(){
            $(this).attr('placeholder',$(this).data('placeholder'));
            $(this).siblings(".clearable").hide();


        });
```

.clearable is a span with background. Normally it is display:none.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove value of span then:

```
$(".search-area").find(".clearable").on("click", function() {
            $(this).text('');
        });
```

if you are trying to remove textbox value then:

```
$(".search-area").on("click",".clearable", function() {
                $(this).closest("#ingredientSearchForm").find('#ingredientsSearch').val('');
            });
```

Comment: I want to remove input's text when clicking span.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're wanting to clear searchinput on clicking .clearable?

If so, you should instead use:

```
$(".search-area").find(".clearable").on("click", function() {
    searchinput.val('');
});
```